# Detached head in git worktree after git pull

Tags: git

I am using `Git 2.6.0 (latest)`, and I am in a git worktree branch. My branch has no local changes, and I would like to simply pull the changes from `origin` into the current branch. But a pull returns a detached HEAD. Can anyone explain me whats happening here?

```
$ git pull origin develop
HEAD is detached from 7a5b7d
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I tried to also do a `git reset --hard` with no success. Any help is highly appreciated!

Please keep in mind, that my current directory is a git worktree. I can't destroy the state of this branch.

Comment: A pull will not of itself give a detached head. Can you show more of what you did? Did you detach when you added the worktree?

Comment: Running `git status` in that work-tree will also show the detached HEAD. It was detached before `git pull`; `git pull` ran a `git merge` anyway, as instructed (or a `git rebase` if you've selected that); and your work-tree may have some other commit(s) in it now as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches`

You will see where `origin/master is` (and where your own local repo HEAD is)

You can then switch to `master`, and reset it to `origin/master` if you want, or merge `origin/master`.

The point is: you has probably a detached HEAD before the `git pull`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it! It was indeed detached before the pull